# Unable to start php-fpm on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm

I am trying to start php8.1-fpm and i get the following error (while php8.0-fpm and php7.4-fpm start correctly). Any help would br greatly appreciated.

```
[root@ ~]# systemctl status php8.1-fpm.service
● php8.1-fpm.service - The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.1-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-06-14 17:06:17 EEST; 5s ago
       Docs: man:php-fpm8.1(8)
    Process: 39682 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.1 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
    Process: 39693 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 81 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 39682 (code=exited, status=78)

Jun 14 17:06:17 domain.com systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager...
Jun 14 17:06:17 domain.com php-fpm8.1[39682]: [14-Jun-2022 17:06:17] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address 'localhost:8002': Address already in use (98)
Jun 14 17:06:17 domain.com php-fpm8.1[39682]: [14-Jun-2022 17:06:17] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Jun 14 17:06:17 domain.com systemd[1]: php8.1-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/CONFIG
Jun 14 17:06:17 domain.com systemd[1]: php8.1-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 14 17:06:17 domain.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 8.1 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you already have a process running on port 8002 in your localhost

identify the process with `netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':8002'` and check if you can kill it or not

If another process need port 8002 you can change php-fpm port in file `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8002          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21610/php-fpm: mast

Comment: this is what i get for port 8002

Comment: Do you have several php version installed ? can it be another one taken the port 8002 ? a test can just be to kill process running on port 8002 and relaunch start php command

Comment: I have a number of servers with similar settings running multiple php versions. I really can't understand what is wrong with this one.

Comment: it's only hypothesis but 1) if you have several php version on a server one can have take the port. 2) if start of php-fpm is done on server start it's already started when you access it 3) another process/cron/admin have already started the process

Comment: It's for sure that `php-fpm` has the port in use and not `php8.1-fpm`. Check your configuration.

Comment: I really hate it when this happens. to have a problem out of the blue nad i can't solve it.

Comment: What else could it cause the problem? any help ?

Comment: 1) you can kill process running on port 8002 and restart php8-1-fpm. 2) if you can't change port of php8.1-fpm in /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and restart it

Comment: I just found out, after a reboot that now php8.0-fpm is not running now and php8.1-fpm is running OK. What the hell is that ???

Comment: it's because you have two version of php installed 8.0 and 8.1. A restart make the latest version of php installed take the port. maybe (but it's always an hypotesis) server have not been restarted since php8.1 installation

Comment: `journalctl -b -u php8.0-fpm` and update your question with all the configs you have.

Comment: I need both versions to be present and running

Comment: so you have to change listening port of one of two versions in something as `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`and restart all

Comment: It's also easier to use sockets instead of ports like `listen = /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock` and `listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock`. This does make you to use the sockets in the other configs like apache/nginx.

Comment: this is the setting i see in both /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and /etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

Comment: What do you see?

Comment: both www.conf files (for 8.0 and 8.1) have this setting listen = /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock and listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock accodringly

Comment: That is alright. Now look in all files for `8002`.

Comment: Problem saved. I found out that in /etc/php/8.x/fpm/pool.d/ there were seperate files for each hosted site is created. Sorting out there the listening ports solved the problem. Thank you all so much !!!

Comment: great happy to have help you to analyse. don't hesitate to mark the reply if it help you to close the topic ;)